# C# and SQL Server database connection error in Destination computer?

Tags: c#, database-connection, connection-string

I create an application in C# and I use a SQL Server database. The problem is when I make a setup file and install it on destination computer, it doesn't work and causes a connection error. I used bunch of connection strings and I still have a problem with this.

The last connection I used:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

But the problem with these connection is I should install SQL Server on destination computer, it doesn't work with compact version. Is there any way to connect database without installing full SQL Server on destination computer?

Comment: is the db placed in the same location on all of the destination machines?

Comment: @Shon yes It is, it's really make me crazy I tried a lot of way but it doesn't work and I am sure I made simple mistake, but don't know what.

Comment: @Shon I read somthing about SQL localdb and I don't know what is that, do you know what is that, what if i use it.

Comment: What error did you get? Any error message?

Comment: If you want to use the `.mdf` files, then you ***must install*** SQL Server (at least **Express**) on that machine - or have a valid SQL Server instance somewhere in the LAN that computer is connected to where you can put your database.

Comment: @marc_s thanks, can I use SQL LocalDB and connect by giving directory path?

Comment: SQL Server LocalDB is a specialized version of SQL Server Express, intended primarily for use during development - not really for deployment. Just install SQL Server **Express** and you're good to go

Comment: @marc_s Thanks a lot my friend.

Comment: @halfer Ok you mean I create answer for my question as I understand, I will add answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not usual to answer my own question but because of friends request I do this, first of all I want to thanks @marc_s because he solved this and tell me the solution, The solution is just install SQLExpress on destination machine and then with correct ConnectionString you can attach your DB on it and then start to use your application, as simple as this.

Comment: And I want thanks to Stackoverflow this is the world greatest programmer Web site.

Comment: @halfer Thanks I understand I made mistake last time, this is really kind of you, thanks a lot to teaching me how to mark solved.